# Banach space with uncountable basis

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, norms

We know that an infinite dimensional Banach space has an uncountable Hamel basis. Now if $X$ is a vector space with an uncountable Hamel basis, does there exist a norm on $X$ for which $X$ is a Banach space. I could not proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are asking in the wrong forum.  When you go to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/ , do some searching to find your answer: For example, a Hamel basis for a Banach space cannot be countably infinite.

Comment: A vector space has no structure other than its dimension, so there can't be any obstructions.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: is it obvious? The Theorem is that if $X$ is Banach, then its Hamel dimension is _not_ $\aleph_0$. I think the OP is asking whether for any cardinal number other than $\aleph_0$ there is a Banach space with that Hamel dimension.

Comment: This [MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4540149/1543) gives a citation that every infinite dimensional  _separable_ Banach space has cardinality exactly $2^{\aleph_0}$. But is there any known result of limits on the cardinalities of non-separable Banach spaces? (Also @MartinBrandenburg.)

Comment: [This MSE comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427834/can-all-real-complex-vector-spaces-be-equipped-with-a-hilbert-space-structure#comment914983_427947) further suggests that there are non-trivial restrictions on the Hamel dimensions of Banach spaces (though I don't understand it at all). I do think this is a suitable question for MO.

Comment: @WillieWong: What I wrote was ambigious and you gave it a stronger than intended interpretation. I just wanted to point out that if there is a Banach space of a given algebraic dimension, then (trivially) any vector space of that dimension will do.

Comment: There is this question on [math.se]: [Can any uncountable dimensional real vector space be made into a Banach space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1658245). (Without a satisfactory answer, at the moment.) And there are some related questions about Hilbert spaces, as already pointed out: 
[Can you equip every vector space with a Hilbert space structure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1100950) and 
[Can all real/complex vector spaces be equipped with a Hilbert space structure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/427834)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Also [A Banach space of (Hamel) dimension $\kappa$ exists if and only if $\kappa^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340939/a-banach-space-of-hamel-dimension-kappa-exists-if-and-only-if-kappa-ale), which answers the question in the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will pull together the comments into a community wiki answer with some of my own remarks so that the question isn't left on the unanswered questions list.

If you're willing to accept that it is consistent that $\aleph_1 < 2^{\aleph_0}$, you can get a relatively small example of an impossible uncountable Hamel dimension for a Banach space. The space $\ell^2$ contains a linearly independent set of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, specifically $(n^{-\alpha})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $\alpha$ ranges over $[0,1]$. So the Hamel dimension of $\ell^2$ is at least $2^{\aleph_0}$, and can't be more because the cardinality of $\ell^2$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$. Now, for every infinite-dimensional Banach space $E$ you can build an injective bounded linear map $\ell^2 \rightarrow E$ (this is one of those constructions where it is simpler to just try it yourself than to follow someone else's way of doing it). So $\dim(E) \geq 2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_1$ and there is no Banach space of Hamel dimension $\aleph_1$.

In general, in Lemma 2 of

> *Kruse, Arthur H.*, [**Badly incomplete normed linear spaces**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01111164), Math. Z. 83, 314-320 (1964). [ZBL0117.08201](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0117.08201).

Kruse showed that for a Banach space $E$, $\dim(E)^{\aleph_0} = \dim(E)$. By König's theorem, if $\kappa$ is uncountable and the union of countably many strictly smaller sets, then $\kappa^{\aleph_0} > \kappa$. So, unconditionally, there is no Banach space of Hamel dimension $\aleph_\omega = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \aleph_n$ nor of Hamel dimension $\beth_\omega = \bigcup \{ 2^{\aleph_0}, 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}, 2^{2^{2^{\aleph_0}}}, \ldots \}$.

(It seems that Kruse's lemma does not require the axiom of replacement. If this is so, then we cannot find an unconditional counterexample without using the axiom of replacement because in the $V_{\omega + \omega}$ inside $L$ we have that $X^{\omega} \cong X$ for every uncountable set.)

Comment: +1 for "this is one of those constructions where it is simpler to just try it yourself".